# Custom C dll for MATLAB - loadlibrary error

Tags: c, windows, matlab, visual-studio-2008

I have a custom dll written for MATLAB and it works fine on our development machines. However, when I try it on a clean machine with no development tools, I get the message:

```
>> loadlibrary CMatLab CMatLab.h
??? Error using ==> loadlibrary at 279
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 or 2008 is required to use this feature.
```

After some research it seemed clear that a compiler was required to parse the header file at runtime, so I installed the standard Windows SDK, ran `mex -setup` to select the compiler but I still get the same error message. This is what I did for select the compiler.

```
>> mex -setup
Please choose your compiler for building external interface (MEX) files: 

Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? mex -setup

Select a compiler: 
[1] Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0 

[0] None 

Compiler: 1

Please verify your choices: 

Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1  
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0 

Are these correct [y]/n? y

*************************************************************************** 
  Warning: MEX-files generated using Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 require 
           that Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 run-time libraries be  
           available on the computer they are run on. 
           If you plan to redistribute your MEX-files to other MATLAB 
           users, be sure that they have the run-time libraries. 
*************************************************************************** 

Trying to update options file: C:\Users\adriane\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2010b\mexopts.bat 
From template:              D:\Matlab\bin\win64\mexopts\msvc90opts.bat 

Done . . .
```

I really do not want to install Visual Studio on this machine as it reduces it's utility as a testbed for release builds of our other tools and software. Any ideas anyone? I see that others have the same problem but I did not see a clear solution. The OS is Windows 7 pro 64 bit. The dll was built with VS2008.

Comment: Not an obvious solution.  Good question and answer.  The dev machine to test machine process is good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the 'MFILENAME' option to `loadlibrary` to produce a "protofile", which can be used in the future to load the DLL via the `@PROTOFILE` syntax.  Generate the file on your development machine, and bring it along to the test machine.

So, on the dev machine:

```
loadlibrary('CMatLab', 'CMatLab.h', 'mfilename', 'cmatlab_proto');
```

Bring along to the test machine the DLL, the file labelled 'thunk', and cmatlab_proto.m.  On the test machine, run:

```
loadlibrary('CMatLab', @cmatlab_proto)
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. That fixed it. I must trawl through the MatLab documentation on this as I would never have found the answer otherwise. The algorithm group have suddenly started smiling.

Comment: +1.  Thanks for the info.  Qs: Can you give a reference to a more detailed description or the relevant docs?  Also, I'm confused about what command to run on the test machine.  Don't you mean that the _test_ machine should run the second command with the "protofile" generated from the first command?  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Yes, good catch on the typo, fixed.  The only docs I found were in `doc loadlibrary`.  It looks like compiler is used to parse the header file, and to generate the thunk interface where necessary.  From the description of the optional protofile interface, I inferred that the compiler wouldn't be needed on subsequent loads, then verified.

Comment: I find that interesting that the compiler might not be required on subsequent calls. I never tried adding the thunk interface before adding a complier.

Comment: The loadlibrary documentation leaves much to be desired. Here's an attempt to fill the blanks on these issues exactly:  https://ofekshilon.com/2016/07/15/on-matlabs-loadlibrary-proto-file-and-pcwin64-thunk/